# Does the GnuTLS bug (CVE-2014-0092) affect the Tor Browser Bundle or Tails?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, linux, tls, ssl

There is a new major security vulnerability in the GnuTLS library ([CVE-2014-0092](http://www.gnutls.org/security.html#GNUTLS-SA-2014-2)) that undermines SSL on (some?) Linux platforms. What versions of the Tor Browser Bundler or Tails (if any) are affected?

(less technical coverage of the issue is at [Arstechnica](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/03/critical-crypto-bug-leaves-linux-hundreds-of-apps-open-to-eavesdropping/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor doesn't use GnuTLS, but OpenSSL. So it is not affected by this vulnerability.
You also might have heard about an attack on SSL (Triple handshake attack). Nick Mathewson wrote an [analysis to tor-dev](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2014-March/006372.html). According to him this also doesn't affect Tor.