# Is Tails affected by the GnuTLS Hello Vulnerability (CVE-2014-3466) ? If so, how?

Tags: security, tails, vulnerability

There are [reports](http://radare.today/technical-analysis-of-the-gnutls-hello-vulnerability/) that many Linux systems are compromised by a recent [critical GnuTLS issue](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-3466). Is Tails affected by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was [fixed in Tails 1.0.1](https://tails.boum.org/security/Numerous_security_holes_in_1.0/).

Answer (score 0):

Referring to a [previous answer to a similar question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/does-the-gnutls-bug-cve-2014-0092-affect-the-tor-browser-bundle-or-tails), Tor uses the OpenSSL library not use GnuTLS for encryption so it is not affected by this vulnerability.